# How to draw navigation drawer in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, navigation-drawer

I need to implement `Navigation drawer` in `ios` (Top to bottom).I found this [github](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) link but it doesn't support top-to-bottom approach. Any hint or guidance will be appreciable.

Comment: Can someone please explain why negative votes?

Comment: This is way too broad for an SO question.

Answer (score 2):

Having vertical menus on iOS are not recommended due to the fact that system menus are already there i.e. Notification Center & Control Center.

If you still want one, you will have to make a custom view on your `UIWindow` or `UIViewController` probably and handle `Pan-gesture` to slide up/down as per your need.